# Trying to run multiple loops in C

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops

I was tasked with creating a program that uses 4 different loops to print the same thing  4 times `(x, x^2, x^3, x!)`. The issue I am having is that only one loop seems to run at a time. How can i make all loops run so that my output looks like:

```
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

Below is the code that I have written so far but i cannot get all of the loops to run simultaneously. My output will only print to the screen once, instead of printing 4 times. Can someone look over my code and let me know where i went wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>

    void main()
    {
    int i =1 ,num;
//Prompt user for an input
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf( "%d", &num);
     if ( num < 0)
            printf("Error: Factorial of negative number doesn't exist.");
     //Loop 1
     for(i = 1; i <= num; i++)

     printf("%d %d %d %d  \n", i, (i) * (i), (i) * (i) * (i), factorial(i));
     //Loop 2
        while(i < num) {
     printf("%d %d %d %d  \n", i, (i) * (i), (i) * (i) * (i), factorial(i));
        i++;
       //Loop 3
        do {
       printf("%d %d %d %d  \n", i, (i) * (i), (i) * (i) * (i), factorial(i));

        i++;
        }while( i < num);

        }   
    //Loop 4 without for, while, do while
    if ( i <= num)
    printf("%d %d %d %d  \n", i, (i) * (i), (i) * (i) * (i), factorial(i));
    i++;
    }


//Function to calculate a factorial

int factorial(int n)

    {
      int c;
      int result = 1;

      for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
        result = result * c;

      return result;
    }
```

The program is designed to take a number from a user and run 4 different loops with that number (for, while, do-while, and a constructed loop via if statement).

Comment: First format&indenty your code! This is an unreadable mess.

Comment: Try doing something else that works, instead of this thing that doesn't work. Why are you set on the "four loops in parallel" idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your variable "i"

You have int i = 1;

Then after 1st for loop i will not be <= num;

```
 int i = 1;
 for loop...//1

 i=1;
 while loop...//2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi your question isn't as clear as we can get it, however you are searching to run loops in parallel way and this is can be done with threads you can check : https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ and i did a simple example without thread if this can help you to complete your work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int n) {
  int c;
  int result = 1;

  for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
    result = result * c;

  return result;
}

void forLoop(int num) {
  static int i = 1;
  int j;
  for(j = 0 ; i <= num && j < 2; i++, j++)
     printf("%d %d %d %d  \n", i, (i) * (i), (i) * (i) * (i), factorial(i));
}

void whileLoop(int num) {
  static int i = 1;
  int j = 0;
  while(i <= num && j < 2) {
    printf("%d %d %d %d  \n", i, (i) * (i), (i) * (i) * (i), factorial(i));
    i++;
    j++;
  }
}

void doWhileLoop(int num) {
  static int i = 1;
  int j = 0;
  do {
    printf("%d %d %d %d  \n", i, (i) * (i), (i) * (i) * (i), factorial(i));
    i++;
    j++;
  } while(i <= num && j < 2);
}
void constructedLoop(int num) {
  static int i = 1;
  int j = 0;
  loop:
    if(i <= num && j < 2) {
      printf("%d %d %d %d  \n", i, (i) * (i), (i) * (i) * (i), factorial(i));
      i++;
      j++;
      goto loop;
    }
}

int main() {
    int i =1 ,num;
//Prompt user for an input
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf( "%d", &num);
  if ( num < 0){
    printf("Error: Factorial of negative number doesn't exist.");
    return 0;
  }
  while(i <= num) {
    forLoop(num);
    whileLoop(num);
    doWhileLoop(num);
    constructedLoop(num);
    i += 2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: so i got that output to print three times. Now i just need some help constructing a final loop without any for, while, or do while constructs. and i cannot use recursion

Comment: no recursion and no loops so you can use goto statement ?

Comment: i can use a goto im just not sure how to properly format it without creating an infinite loop

Comment: i edited the code now you can check the new code i added a constructedLoop function using if and goto statements